# Need to print kNN K's together with NNF / STFT covariance matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Challenge on printing print kNN K's together with NNF / STFT covariance matrix**

**Effort works for summary covariance but need solution to print print kNN K's together with NNF / STFT covariance matrix in a bar plot that has kNN and PCA on the x axis and the accuracy on the y axis.

**Question**

How to print kNN K's together with NNF / STFT covariance matrix such that the individual convergence prints on the accuracy of the kNN model with individual x axis on for example, PCA 5, 10, 15, 20, etc and that are in line with the NNF / STFT covariance matrix on the x axis for performance on each kNN or PCA.

Here is an example of what I hope to achieve, but having problems in correctly formatting this approach:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Have the bar plot, say PCS mapped to partial (PA) and full covariance (C).

**Current working covariance bar plot**

y axis --> ...0.55|0.54.....0.65|0.63.....0.70|0.72....0.72|0.75

x axis --> ..........5...................10..................15.................20

[Note: ...for spacing here only]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Code that generated bar chart:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, cov_diagonals, width, label='Diagonal Covariance Matrix')
bars2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, cov_fulls, width, label='Full Covariance Matrix')

ax.set_ylabel('Covariance')
ax.set_title('Comparison of Diagonal and Full Covariance Matrices')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(methods)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Utilizing several custom code for the following functions:

**Base Functions**

```
from scipy.signal import stft
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF

def set_dft_matrix(dim_size):
    matrix = np.array([[np.exp(-1j * (2 * np.pi * f * n / dim_size)) for f in range(0, dim_size)] for n in range(0, dim_size)])
    return matrix

def set_blackman_window(signal, N, hop):
    matrix_blackman = np.blackman(N)
    data = []
    window_hop = 0    
    while window_hop + N <= len(data):
        signal_frame = data[window_hop: window_hop+N]
        v = np.multiply(signal_frame.T, matrix_blackman)
        data.append(v)
        window_hop = window_hop + hop
    return np.array(data).T

def set_mu_stft(signal, num_channel, nperseg, noverlap):
    stft = []
    dft = set_dft_matrix(64)
    for m in range(num_channel):
        channel = set_blackman_window(signal[:,i], nperseg, noverlap)
        mu = np.abs(np.dot(dft, channel))[2:7,:].reshape(-1,1)
        stft.append(mu)     
    return np.array(stft).reshape(-1,1)

def compute_covariance_matrix(eeg):
    flattened = eeg.reshape(eeg.shape[0], -1)
    standardized = (flattened - np.mean(flattened, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]) / np.std(flattened, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    diag_matrix = np.var(standardized, axis=1)
    full_matrix = np.cov(standardized)
    return diag_matrix, full_matrix

def feature_extraction(eeg, method='NMF', n_components=10):
    if method == 'NMF':
        nmf = NMF(n_components=n_components)
        features = nmf.fit_transform(eeg.reshape(eeg.shape[0], -1))
    elif method == 'STFT':
        _, _, features = stft(eeg, fs=128, nperseg=64, noverlap=48, window='blackman', axis=2)
        features = features.reshape(eeg.shape[0], -1)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid feature extraction method")
    return features


def customized_nmf(matrix, lr=0.01, max_iterations=5000, convergence_threshold=1e-3):
    prev_obj = np.full(matrix.shape, np.inf)
    w = np.random.rand(matrix.shape[0], 10)
    h = np.random.rand(10, matrix.shape[1])

    for i in range(max_iterations):
        o = 0.5 * np.trace(np.transpose(matrix - np.matmul(w, h)))
        o *= (matrix - np.matmul(w, h))

        prev_w = w.copy()
        prev_h = h.copy()
        w_update = lr * (np.matmul(w, np.matmul(h, np.transpose(h))) - np.matmul(matrix, np.transpose(h)))
        h_update = lr * (np.matmul(np.matmul(np.transpose(w), w), h) - np.matmul(np.transpose(w), matrix))

        w -= w_update
        h -= h_update

        if i == 1000:
            lr /= 10

        if np.allclose(prev_obj, o, atol=convergence_threshold, rtol=convergence_threshold):
            print("Converged at ", i)
            break

        prev_obj = o.copy()

    return w, h

def kNN(train, test, k, labels):
    power = np.sqrt(np.power((train - test), 2))
    label = labels
    d = dict(zip(power, label))
    smallest = np.argsort(power)[:k]
    return [d[x] for x in smallest]

def kNN_neighbors(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y, k):
    distances = []
    
    for i in range(len(train_x)):
        measurement = euclidean_distance(test_x, train_x[i])
        distances.append((measurement, train_y[i]))
        
    distances.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    kNN = distances[:k]
    kNN_neighbors = [n[1][0] for n in kNN]
    
    return(max(kNN_neighbors, key = kNN_neighbors.count))

from scipy.signal import stft
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF

# Customized NMF function
def customized_nmf(matrix, lr=0.01, max_iterations=5000, convergence_threshold=1e-3):
    prev_obj = np.full(matrix.shape, np.inf)
    w = np.random.rand(matrix.shape[0], 10)
    h = np.random.rand(10, matrix.shape[1])

    for i in range(0, max_iterations):
        o = 0.5 * np.trace(np.transpose(matrix - np.matmul(w, h)))
        o *= (matrix - np.matmul(w, h))
        prev_w = w.copy()
        prev_h = h.copy()
        w -= lr * (np.matmul(w, np.matmul(h, np.transpose(h))) - np.matmul(matrix, np.transpose(h)))
        h -= lr * (np.matmul(np.matmul(np.transpose(w), w), h) - np.matmul(np.transpose(w), matrix))
        if i == 1000:
            lr /= 10
        if np.allclose(prev_obj, o, atol=convergence_threshold, rtol=convergence_threshold):
            print("Converged at ", i)
            break
        prev_obj = o.copy()

    return w, h

def feature_extraction(eeg_data, method='NMF', n_components=10):
    if method == 'NMF':
        nmf = NMF(n_components=n_components)
        features = nmf.fit_transform(eeg_data.reshape(eeg_data.shape[0], -1))
        w, h = customized_nmf(features)
    elif method == 'STFT':
        _, _, features = stft(eeg_data, fs=128, nperseg=64, noverlap=48, window='blackman', axis=2)
        features = features.reshape(eeg_data.shape[0], -1)
        w, h = None, None  # Dummy values
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid feature extraction method")
    return features, w, h

def compute_covariance_matrices(eeg_features):
    flattened_data = eeg_features.reshape(eeg_features.shape[0], -1)
    standardized_data = (flattened_data - np.mean(flattened_data, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]) / np.std(flattened_data, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    cov_diag = np.var(standardized_data, axis=1)
    cov_full = np.cov(standardized_data)
    return cov_diag, cov_full


# Generate synthetic EEG data
num_recordings = 112
num_channels = 3
sample_rate = 128  # samples per second
duration = 6  # seconds

# Compute covariance matrices for NMF and STFT
eeg = np.array(eeg)

nmf_features, nmf_w, nmf_h = feature_extraction(eeg, method='NMF')
stft_features, _, _ = feature_extraction(eeg, method='STFT')
diag_nmf_mat, full_nmf_mat = compute_covariance_matrices(nmf_features)
diag_stft_mat, full_stft_mat = compute_covariance_matrices(stft_features)

methods = ['NMF', 'STFT']
cov_diagonals = [np.mean(diag_nmf_mat), np.mean(diag_stft_mat)]
cov_fulls = [np.mean(full_nmf_mat), np.mean(full_stft_mat)]

x = np.arange(len(methods))
width = 0.35
```

**Data Samples**

```
          0.04931641,  0.01171875],
        [-0.00830078,  0.02441406, -0.015625  , ..., -0.10400391,
          0.03320312, -0.02587891],
        [ 0.00634766,  0.0546875 ,  0.01806641, ..., -0.15332031,
         -0.03222656, -0.01660156]],

       [[ 0.03466797,  0.01660156, -0.10742188, ..., -0.11669922,
         -0.00048828, -0.05615234],
        [-0.02197266, -0.00390625, -0.02685547, ..., -0.10595703,
          0.04931641, -0.0546875 ],
        [-0.00146484,  0.03271484, -0.05224609, ..., -0.11132812,
          0.02783203, -0.04345703]],

       [[-0.02441406,  0.01611328, -0.14013672, ..., -0.06933594,
         -0.01806641, -0.17041016],
        [-0.04882812, -0.01464844, -0.07080078, ..., -0.07666016,
          0.07421875, -0.10498047],
        [-0.03369141, -0.01855469, -0.11474609, ..., -0.12646484,
          0.07519531, -0.07617188]]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHa7T.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5IEm.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOm9H.png
```